# Docker stack memory reservation

Tags: docker, devops

I'm using both memory reservations and limits in my Docker stack. There is something I haven't found clearly stated in the Docker documentation. Let's say I have a service with the following resource limits and reservations:

```
deploy:
  replicas: 1
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 2g
    reservations:
      memory: 2g
```

Does this mean that 2GB of the RAM of the machine will be exclusive reserved to this service and can't be used by others?. There are some services that have memory spikes but don't use their memory most of the time so I would like to have other containers use that memory space now and then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reserve-memory switch is a configuration for cgroup. You can read [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/758864) for your question.

reserve-memory is not guaranteed hard memory reservation for your container in the system. It's a guarantee that the container will not be started if haven't enough memory for a run.